# How to manipulate an Organization Secret var with an input var in Github Actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

In my project, we have some secrets which are shared between Github Repositories via GH Organisation Secrets.

Currently we are facing the following the issue. Every repository has access to some credentials with the following format:

- SAMPLE_APP_DEV_ACCESS
- SAMPLE_APP_INT_ACCESS
- SAMPLE_APP_PROD_ACCESS

We would like to develop a github action where users give as an input the desired env (DEV, INT or PROD) and then using the relevant secret they are able to connect to the corresponding env.

My question is the following:

> Is there any one-liner to achieve this?

**Edit 08/09/2023:**

The following line did the trick

```
${{ secrets[format('SAMPLE_APP_{0}_ACCESS', inputs.environment)] }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue turned out to be related to a typo in our configured secret name. I am closing the thread and updating it to include the solution.